# using a variable as an image source in html? (python)

Tags: python, html, django, image

Before I start please pardon my english, totally newbie in HTML and this is the very first django app I'm creating.

So let's say I want to view static images based on the input in the forms for testing purpose, so if I type in the form *goat.jpg* it will display goat.jpg

this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

<html>

<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center><img src="{% static "{{staticpath}}" %}" alt="gif" align="middle"/></center>
    {{boldmessage}}
```

and this is my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def generate(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.GET:
        path = request.GET.get('path','')
    context_dict = {'staticpath':path}
    return render_to_response("generated/generated.html", context_dict, context)
```

path is already a string, but if I remove the staticpath double quote django will raise an exception. So how do I exactly put the path's string in the html image source so it will display the static images correctly? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling {% static 'some/path/' %} will call the Django [static file finders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders). If the image you are looking for is in a directory and you only pass the file name to {% static 'some/path' %} it will not find the file.

Read about the {{ STATIC_URL }} tag as solution that will avoid nesting tags. If your files are all stored in the root folder of your staticfiles directory (set by the STATIC_ROOT setting in settings.py) then this will work-
`<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ staticpath }}"/>`
However, it would probably be best to implement a function called by your view that SEARCHES your STATIC_ROOT folder, and all child folders, to find the full relative ( to STATIC_ROOT ) path for the file and returns it. The approach is convoluted but would work.